# CSS Lbrace missing

Tags: css, syntax-error, braces

I've adjusted the CSS code of an element in Chrome browser inspector.

When copy-pasting the CSS change into the custom CSS editor of my website's template, I get an error message stating

`Expected LBRACE at line 2, col 1.`

The copy pasted CSS code is,

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.vc_col-sm-6 {
     width: 35%;
}
```

where I adjusted the width from `50%` to `35%`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .vc_col-sm-6 {
    width: 35%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I'll accept when I can. Any reason why Chrome automatically copy-pastes with an error?

Comment: @LucSpan Maybe it's not meant to be copied, but only to inform that these styles are only applied when these media queries are matched. Anyway, you can always click the link `<filename>:<line-number>` to open the original stylesheet and copy it from there.